# .net 7 Web Api can't read appsetting.json on vps deployment

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, vps

I am deploying my web api to Ubuntu 23.04 installed VPS. I have installed .net 7 sdk and nginx etc. But when i try to access the api from any api app to request some data i get this error:

> 'Connection id "0HMT9CF8GN50H", Request id "0HMT9CF8GN50H:00000001":
> An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> SoriooWebApi[365268]:       System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')'

It's JWT Bearer error actually, here is the Program.cs:

```
    global using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using Retyoo.Data;
    using Retyoo.Data.Auth;
    using Retyoo.Models;
    using Retyoo.WebApi.Data.Auth;
    using Retyoo.WebApi.Mappings;
    using Retyoo.WebApi.Helpers;
    using Retyoo.WebApi.Services;
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Add services to the container.
    //Add DB
    
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    
    
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
    // builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => {
    //     options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RetyooDatabase"), assembly => assembly.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(AppDbContext).Assembly.FullName));
    // });
    
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => {
        options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SoriooDB"), assembly => assembly.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(AppDbContext).Assembly.FullName));
    });
    
    //Email config
    builder.Services.Configure<EmailSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration"));
    
    //Add Identity
    builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
        options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
        
    })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    
    //Config Identity
    builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => 
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        }
    );
    
    //Add Authentication and JwtBearer
    builder.Services
        .AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:ValidIssuer"],
                ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:ValidAudience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["AppSettings:Secret"]!)),
            };
        })
.AddGoogle(googleOptions => {
        googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:GoogleWebClientId"]!;
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:ClientSecret"]!;
            
        });
        
    
    builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfiles).Assembly);
    
    //Inject app Dependencies (DI)
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenRepository, TokenRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IImageService, ImageService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ISellerService, SellerService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ISellerCompanyService, SellerCompanyService>();
    
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
    
    //pipeline
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    } else {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapControllers();
    
    app.Run();
```

Here is the appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SoriooDB": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=sorioodb;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;"
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "ValidIssuer": "http://localhost:5000",
    "ValidAudience": "http://localhost:3000",
    "Secret": "Asdad9DSADAOSDJADA=D)ASDAJADSALKSAD=ASKASDlkerjelkjadaşkAADKLJLK)=(098098ASDJKHkmKJHmnnbvv===",
    "RefreshTokenValidityInDays": 7
  },
  "EmailConfiguration": {
    "From": "xxx",
    "SmtpServer": "xxx",
    "Port": 587,
    "UserName": "xxx",
    "Password": "xxx"
  },
  "Authentication": {
    "GoogleWebClientId": "xxx",
    "GoogleAndroidClientId": "xxx",
    "GoogleIOSClientId": "xxx",
    "ClientSecret": "xxx"
  }
}
```

Here is the systemd file for the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=SoriooWebApi

[Service]
WorkingDirectory /home/app/SoriooWebApi
ExecStart=dotnet /home/app/SoriooWebApi/Retyoo.WebApi.dll
SyslogIdentifier=SoriooWebApi
User=ubuntu
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i publish the api on my localhost, i have no error also i can see the appsettings.json, appsettings.Production.json files in the published folder. I can't really find the problem.

Comment: To debug. put some log at top of program.cs and check the environment name and also check existence for appsettings files

Comment: Do you have appsettings.Production.json? If yes, can you list it? And also please provide your Program.cs -- the part where you set Configuration

Comment: @GeorgyTarasov i have added appsetting.Production.js and full Program.cs to the question.

Answer (score 0):

That was my mistake, it's been 2 days i have been working on this problem and finally found the problem. The problem is to add '=' on service file line 5 which is "WorkingDirectory". How i found is a coincidence because when i try to check service status with "journalctl" command there was a warning which says the missing '=' at line 5 but this was my, to say, 40th check and finally i saw that message. Added '=' and now it's working...